# file_get_contents(composer.json): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: laravel

I moved a laravel project into api folder, but left composer.json in root foolder

- /root

  - /api
  - any folders
  - .env
  - composer.json
  - artisan

When I ran `php artisan make:model` Model

I got an error:  `file_get_contents(/.../api/composer.json): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

How do I change the path to the composer.json file for artisan, it is important for me that the composer.json file left in the root?

Comment: I have the same error on a prod server. Why is composer.json needed in a Laravel production env?

Answer (score 0):

if you use absolute path could be better for you coding, you should use this `app_path` global helper,

```php
file_get_contents(app_path('composer.json'))
```

or you can use the base path

```php
 $basePath=app()->basePath()
```

Comment: Thanks. This is in vendor. I want to just change the path to the composer.json file so that I can use artisan